# Determinant of a matrix with entries specified by a set

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $K$ is an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues between $0$ and $1$. Let $E\subset \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. I wonder how to show that det$(M^{E})\geq 0$, where $M^{E}$ is defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
    M^{E}\left(i,j\right)=\begin{cases}
    \delta_{i,j}-K(i,j)&\text{, }i\in E^{\complement}\\
    K(i,j)&\text{, otherwise}
    \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stress the dependence of $M^E$ on $K$, let us use the symbol $M^E_K$ instead of $M^E$ for the moment. When $t\in[0,1]$, $K_t=tI+(1-t)K$ is a positive definite matrix with eigenvalues between $0$ and $1$. Since $\det(M^E_K)=\lim_{t\to0}\det(M^E_{K_t})$, it suffices to prove that $\det(M^E_{K_t})\ge0$. In other words, we may assume that $K$ is positive definite.

Without loss of generality, we may also assume that $E=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ for some $m\le n$. If we write
$$
K=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Y^\ast&Z},
$$
where $X$ is $m\times m$, then
$$
M_E=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ -Y^\ast&I_{n-m}-Z}.
$$
Since $K$ is positive definite, so is $X=K(E,E)$. Moreover, we have $\rho(Z)=\|Z\|_2\le\|K\|_2\le1$. Therefore both $Y^\ast XY$ and $I-Z$ are positive semidefinite. So, by using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we obtain
$$
\det(M)=\det(X)\det(I-Z+Y^\ast X^{-1}Y)\ge0
$$
because $X$ is positive definite and $I-Z+Y^\ast X^{-1}Y$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder is there any theorem out there saying that the spectral radius of $Z$ is less than the spectral radius of $K$?

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 Yes. You may use Cauchy's interlacing inequality or Courant-Fischer minimax principle. Both imply that $\lambda_\min(K)\le\lambda_\min(Z)$ and $\lambda_\max(Z)\le\lambda_\max(K)$. It follows that $\rho(Z)\le\rho(K)$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. One last question is that what if $X$ is a singular matrix? Is this the reason you mentioned the continuity argument?

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 Yes, I want $X$ to be nonsingular so that its Schur complement exists.

Comment: Can $X$ be singular if $K$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 Yes, why not? Consider $K=0$ for instance.

Comment: In fact I'm not quite sure how continuity argument makes the assumption that $K$ is positive definite legitimate since $K$ is in fact positive semi-definite. Then $X^{-1}$ may not exist since $X$ can be singular.

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 Please see if the new edit helps.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks.